# R wide long format range

Tags: r, seq

I have the following problem in R language:

*I would like to reshape my data from a wide format e.g.*

```
id1 time_start time_end   name1  name2
345 jan.3.6:00 jan.4.7:00 Daniel Roland
346 jan.3.6:10 jan.3.6:30 Elen   Roland
```

*to a long format with one data in each second like:*

```
time_in_hours id variablename value
jan.3.6:00 345 name1 Daniel
jan.3.6:00 345 name2 Roland
jan.3.7:00 345 name1 Daniel
jan.3.7:00 345 name2 Roland
```

So I need a seq in the given range, and transform the values in a long format. I would like to ask some advice how to do it. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please format the data and show some real values

Comment: Thank you, very much for the critic and the edit as well! I will try to improve my questions. And thanks for the solved problem as well (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format). Though I do not think it is a duplicate, I have to generate a sequence for times and not just reshape already existing dates to long format.